# Jquery select specific element

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a list of radio tags with a diffrent id(post-1,post2 etc).

I am trying to preforme get request with the specific post id by clickign the radio.
This is the html:

```js
$("#pro").click(function(){
     var post = $(this).val();
    alert(post);   
  $.get("<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/jquery.php",{type: 'post',  userid :'<?php echo get_current_user_id();?>', postid: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>', pro : "pro"},function(data,status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); 
  });
});
```

```html
<input type = "radio" value = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" class="pro-radio" name="pro-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" id="pro"  <?php echo $GLOBALS['lock']; ?> <?php echo $pro_select; ?>> <label for="pro" class="pro-radio" >pro</label>
```

and this is the jquery:

When I press one of them, all of the radios oprate the jquery.

Thank you.

Comment: Because all of them have the same id

Comment: Post the rendered HTML; the PHP is irrelevant here.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't agree with what you say in the first line. You have different names, but the same ID. It looks like you got them backwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think you reverted name and ids, 
try this html

```
<input type = "radio" value = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" class="pro-radio" id="pro-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" name="pro"  <?php echo $GLOBALS['lock']; ?> <?php echo $pro_select; ?>> <label for="pro" class="pro-radio" >pro</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a different class for each radio button and select by class name
    var post = $('.className').val();
    alert(post);

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML is a bit weird. You use the same `id` but different `name` attributes for your radios. Assume, you have this HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="pro" value="1" id="pro-1"> <label for="pro-1">pro 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="pro" value="2" id="pro-2"> <label for="pro-2">pro 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="pro" value="3" id="pro-3"> <label for="pro-3">pro 3</label>
```

Then use this JS to get the selected value:

```
$('input[name=pro]').change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Please note, that the radios are selected by their (identical) `name`, but not by the (different) `id`. Then you have to verify the current element is the selected one using `.is(':checked')` and  finally I use `change()` instead of `click()` if the element is selected via keyboard input.

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/seofu1t4/

Comment: There a samll issue I didnt told. each post has 2 radois(pro and against) , so this is why the name is pro-#number. Now, when I click on one of the radios elements the jquery gets the click and sends 5 times( 5 is the number of the posts I have) the same get request.